# When cron is completed How to get email notification and log in a file (both)

Tags: centos, email, logging, cron

I am a Newbie to linux. I'm trying to figure out things. Can someone kindly help me how to combine these two commands?

(1) Normally cron can results can be directed to a log file by editing crontab in the below manner

```
*/10 * * * * /scripts/mysc.sh >> /home/ara/Desktop/test/log.txt 2>&1
```

(2) and in case we need cron results to be emails we can use `MAILTO=someemail@domain.com` such as

```
MAILTO=someemail@domain.com
*/10 * * * * /scripts/mysc.sh
```

But how to combine both options (1) and (2)? I have seen some webhosting space do have both options enabled simultaneously. I did my research/googling but failed to do it. I'm using centos 6.5 and use `crontab -e` to edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first example sends both stderr and stdout to the file (2>&1) ; the MAILTO variable set in the cron will capture any output that is not redirected, and this combined with directing the output to the file means that no output is available for the cron to email.

I'd suggest using tee to append the output to the file as well as sending it to stdout; this answer - https://serverfault.com/a/472878/102867 - is very similar one to what you're asking to acheive.

Alternatively, follow the suggestion in the first answer, and write a wrapper script to more gracefully handle the output of the script, and you can then both log, and have the output of your script mailed

Comment: I could achieve that by reading above answer and what i did was this

    /scripts/mysc.sh >> /home/ara/Desktop/test/log.txt 2>&1; mailx -s "Cron output"  someemail@domain.com < /home/ara/Desktop/test/log.txt

thanks Andrew

Comment: @user3107413 That way you will always send the complete, ever increasing logfile via email. Do you want that? If not, better use `tee`.

Comment: hi Dubu.. Not sure what is the exact syntax.. Tried several times.. but failed .. not familiar with prod nor tee command syntax or functions.. thanks for helping ..

Comment: Finally this thing works perfect....... MAILTO=someemail@domain.com */3 * * * * /scripts/mysc.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /home/ara/Desktop/test/log.txt Thanks Dubu

Answer (score 2):

Cronjob for both log & email :

Run once a month at midnight of the first day of the month: `0 0 1 * *`

```
0 0 1 * * /home/User/script.sh > /home/User/cronlog/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S`-cron.log 2>&1 ; mailx -s "CronJob is run successfully" someone@domain.com,someone1@domain.com
```